# Rails3: Precomputing/storing data for graphs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graph, highcharts

I'm currently building a little admin platform with statistics and graphs with highchart and highstock. Right now the graphs are always fetching the data from the database everytime the load. But since the data will grow substantially in the future this is very inefficient and slows the database down. My question now is what the best approach it would be to store or precompute the data so the graphs don't have to fetch it from the database everytime they load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the amount of data is going to be really huge and you can sacrifice some realtime-ish manner of presenting it, the best way would be to compute the data for charts in some seperate database table and show the charts out of it. You can setup a background process (using [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) or [delayed_job](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or whatever you like) to periodically update the pre-processed data table with fresh values.

Another option would be caching the chart response by any means you like (using built-in Rails caching, writing your custom cache etc) to deliver the same data to a big number of users with reduced DB hit.

However, in general, preprocessing seems to be the winner as stats tables usually contain very "sparse" data which can be pre-computed to a much smaller set to display on a chart yet having the option to apply some filtering / sorting if needed.

**EDIT** just forgot to mention there might be some room for optimization on the database side. For instance, if you can limit the periods the user is able to view data for (= cap the amount to be queried per used), than proper indexing and DB setup can deliver substantial performance without man-in-the middle things like caching or precomputing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is it enough to just store the data in another table, or should I store it in a completely seperate database?

Comment: To be ultimately precise, for your case it HAS to be a separate database. The problem is that you main table (which stores raw stats) is supposed to be heavily used all the time (as you mention you are going to continuosly collect stats) plus it will be queried by the pre-processing tool, which would put the additional load the database. This way, you'd better put stats table on a separate DB, while the DB for the web interface resides on a different machine, so that web site usage doesn't affect stats collection and vice versa.

Comment: And yep, one more option is to set up DB master-slave replication, where stats table would be a master one and will replicate raw table to a slave instance. This way you can screw the slave instance with long-running queries for as much as you like with (almost) no effect on the master. This would keep stats fully operation, but might still deliver some bad user experience to charting feature.